# Understanding window with watermark in Apache Spark Structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have one misunderstanding about Spark Structured Streaming docs. I have read it many times. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html
Here is written:

> "For a specific window starting at time T, the engine will maintain state and allow late data to update the state until (max event time seen by the engine - late threshold > T)."

This means that T here is beginning of window which state if maintained, am I correct?

I.e. when this condition (max event time seen by the engine - late threshold > T) will start to be met window starting at T will not be updated anymore.
watermark = max event time seen by the engine - late threshold.
But later we can see use cases where T seems to be end of this window.

> "However, when the watermark is updated to 12:11, the intermediate state for window (12:00 - 12:10) is cleared, and all subsequent data (e.g. (12:04, donkey)) is considered “too late” and therefore ignored. Note that after every trigger, the updated counts (i.e. purple rows) are written to sink as the trigger output, as dictated by the Update mode."

So we stop updating window cause wm > 12:10(window end), not 12:00(window start), right? and T have to be end of window?

Comment: The watermark is is last seen event time - late threshold. So if the last seen event time is 12:11 and the late threshold is 10 minutes the watermark is 12:01. Since 12:01 is later than the window start time of 12:00 it's state is dropped. T is always the start of the window just as the article says.

Comment: it's written "However, when the watermark is updated to 12:11, the intermediate state for window (12:00 - 12:10) is cleared". So 12:11 is already last_evt_time_seen_by_window-threshold, 12:11 is already result of of subtraction not last event time seen by engine

Comment: Reread it and yes, I believe you are correct. They never use T as if it was the start of the window except when they define it. Probably ought to be updated. Quite interesting, I somehow thought event time of late events mattered in relation to the watermark (ie if later than the watermark they are dropped). It seems as if events older than the watermark but still within a window still in scope is added to the window (although they don't explicitly show that case). The watermark is only relevant to keep track of which windows are finished.

Comment: I have send email to spark community few days ago but for now no response. And I still dont see it in list of emails here http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com. Maybe I have to wait or there's another way to contact them?